# How do I search for a username in new Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to search for a username. Would like to search "alan" and get the id associated with it.

This is my database:
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Post your code and lets take a look. Also, in this case, you don't need to search for alan as you know where he is already.  /users/usernames/alan. Observe that node and the value in the snapshot will be the id associated with it. One other comment: this structure will probably lead you into coding trouble. Users should have the uid as the parent node key and then children of name: alan  age: 45 for each user.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the new Firebase is Firebase 3.x and that users is under the root with JavaScript you can do:

```
         firebase.database().ref('users/usernames/alan').on('value', (snapshot) => {    
                    //Get id for Alan     
                    var id = snapshot.val()
            })
```

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this code should work - you can also add comments in the code itself - in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question.

Comment: It's for a user search to add to a group chat. What if there's thousands of users? I was hoping to use a queryValueEqualTo, but can't get that to work.

And yes, it's the new firebase, Swift, and users is under root.

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty old but just wanted to answer that you can absolutely use a query.
You also don't have to set it up as a listener unless you need that functionality.
Something like:

```
firebase.database().ref('users/usernames').where('username', '==', 'alan').then(()=>{

  //do some stuff

})
```

would do what I think you are asking.